# Getting request body from response object

Tags: node.js, buffer, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to retrieve the body of a request via the response object.

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    ...
    body: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
}, function(err, res, body) {
    var reqBody = res.request.body;
});
```

But the request body is now a Buffer. How can I turn this back into a JavaScript object?

Note: I can't store the request body in a variable with larger scope before making the http request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, way simpler than I thought.

```
var reqBody = res.request.body.toString();
reqBody = JSON.parse(reqBody);
```

First convert it to JSON, then convert the JSON to a JavaScript object.

Comment: that 'toString' on body doesn't work, i have to use JSON.stringify